# Maintaining FindBugs bug history

Tags: static-analysis, findbugs

FindBugs provides a way to do [data mining](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/datamining.html) of bugs. That looks interesting as it helps in trending of bugs over various revisions. What I want to do is:

On each commit to version control, FindBugs will be run and a report will be generated. Is it possible to generate a report that takes data from all these reports and shows the trend? Has anyone done something similar?

Answer (score 1):

[Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) (the CI server) can do that for you.